# Can't mount ISO image in Windows 8 inside VMWare Fusion

Tags: windows-8, vmware-fusion

When I try to mount an image (in this case, Project Pro 2013) in Windows 8 that is running inside a virtual machine (VMWare Fusion, running on OSX) I get the following message

> Couldn't Mount File
>
> Virtual hard disk files can't be mounted from image files, or from removable media that isn't formatted with NTFS file system.
>
> [ OK ]

This same image file mounts perfectly fine in OSX, is this situation specific to VMWare and if so, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Copy ISO to your virtual NTFS harddrive (C:) and mount it.

Comment: I had the same error and this answer corrected the issue.

Comment: I had the same issue in virtualbox, and this fixed it too.

Comment: I had this problem with Parallels Desktop 11 for Mac. Mounting the image using OSX and then connecting to the drive from within the VM worked.

Answer (score 3):

There is one of two things going wrong here:

- Your Project 2013 ISO is sitting on an external storage medium that is not formatted with the NTFS file system.
- You are trying to mount a ISO file as a HDD instead of a CD-Rom.

Comment: Could it be that you have the MSDN iso file on the Mac filesystem and have shared the folder containing the iso file from within VMWare? If so you will get the error you indicated since Windows 8 is seeing the iso on the HFS filesystem. Copy/Move the iso over to the Windows 8 filesystem from within VMWare and then you should be able to open it. Worked for me :) Essentially this is what @TaylorGibb was saying in his first bullet point.

Answer (score 1):

Connect the ISO image as a CD-ROM, not as a hard drive.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I have always copied to file to the vm's hard disk. In Hyper-V just go to Media--> DVD drive -> Insert disk.
That's it.